# Import csv data into SQL Server with a file dialog

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I have a C# application which gives me as an output CSV files. Currently I am using the manual import assistant of SQL Server to import those CSV files into the database. In addition I used Integration Services to create a foreach loop container to import the data automatically into the database.

What I would like to have is, the opportunity to **open a file dialog**,select the data and then automatically import the selected data into the database. I guess that one solution is to do this in C#  or to include it into the existing C# application. Is there any opportunity to do this in SQL Server 2012 or integration service? Thanks for your help

Comment: AFAIK, you would have to code this. Good news is it's relatively easy to do in C#

Comment: Thanks then I will do it in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BULK INSERT command which is pretty fast and you can specify your field separator and row terminator. You can execute this command as a sql query by passing the file path as a parameter.

```
BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
   FROM 'f:\orders\lineitem.tbl'  
   WITH (  
     FIELDTERMINATOR =' |',  
     ROWTERMINATOR =' |\n'  
  );
```

For more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx